# SpriteKit SKSpriteNode fills entire scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to add a `SKSpriteNdoe` to my scene but for some reason the image fills the entire scene even if the image size is 50x50 pixels.

Here's my code:

```swift
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"my-sprite")
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                          y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
addChild(sprite)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the sprite's `size` property?

Comment: What is the size of your scene?

Comment: Thanks! the problem was the scene size